# Create expandable <div> with jquery within expandable <div>

Tags: jquery, css, containers, expandable

I have found this code to create an expandable/collapsible a while ago while trying to build an expandable Div-Container and it has worked wonders for me so far (unexperienced hobby designer here).

Now I would like to insert an expandable div within one of those. The problem I am facing is that I cannot figure out how to change the function in order so it automatically readjusts the outer height of the first expandable div. I have an example of what it should look like here (If I expand Collapsible 1-3 it should also expand Collapsible 1 so all content is visible):

Collapsible 1

- Collapsible 1-1
- Collapsible 1-2
- Collapsible 1-3

The code I use can be found here:

HTML:

```
<button id="button">Toggle Expand/Collapse</button>
<div id="wrapper" class="open">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
background: #ccc;
overflow: hidden;
transition: height 200ms;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
var b = $("#button");
var w = $("#wrapper");
var l = $("#list");

w.height(l.outerHeight(true));

b.click(function() {

 if(w.hasClass('open')) {
   w.removeClass('open');
   w.height(0);
 } else {
  w.addClass('open');
  w.height(l.outerHeight(true));
 }

 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.slideDown` and `.slideUp` instead of calculating height.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('open').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*transition: height 200ms;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Toggle Expand/Collapse</button>
<div id="wrapper" class="open">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```